# Spree (rails) won't let me create a migration. Says there is a conflict within i18n.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, spree

I asked rails to create a migration with the following command:

```
$ rails g migration add_sale_price_to_spree_variants sale_price:decimal
```

It fails and returns the following output:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2098:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate spree_core-2.3.1, because i18n-0.6.11 conflicts with i18n (= 0.6.9) (Gem::ConflictError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1286:in `activate'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:196:in `rescue in try_activate'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:193:in `try_activate'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
from /Users/byronshilly/Desktop/store/spree_simple_sales/lib/spree_simple_sales/engine.rb:3:in `<class:Engine>'
from /Users/byronshilly/Desktop/store/spree_simple_sales/lib/spree_simple_sales/engine.rb:2:in `<module:SpreeSimpleSales>'
from /Users/byronshilly/Desktop/store/spree_simple_sales/lib/spree_simple_sales/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine/commands.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
from bin/rails:7:in `<main>'
```

If you scroll to the right, you'll see `Unable to activate spree_core-2.3.1, because i18n-0.6.11 conflicts with i18n (= 0.6.9) (Gem::ConflictError)`

I've been having problems left and right with that dependency, if that's what it is. Anyone know how I can resolve this? The current spree guide is very problematic, even though I am following it step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention the correct way is to use

```
bundle exec
```

This happen because in your spree app is using a i18n version different that the one install in your system.

Bundler offers the solution in that way. http://bundler.io/v1.1/bundle_exec.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding `bundle exec` to the beginning of the command fixed the issue. Not sure how proper this is.